# Quality of Affine Transformation (between two set of matching points)

Tags: image-processing, distance, matching, least-squares, affinetransform

I'm trying to compare two human poses with each other. I have the 18 body-joint points of the two poses that need to be compared. 
So we have 2 sets of matching points, the model X (which needs to be mimicked) and the input Y (needs to be checked on matching grade).
In order to do so, the affine transformation A (transforms X to Y) is calculated. Then, now A is know, the projection of X on Y ( = X*A) is calculated (least-squares). 
Finally, deciding if the poses are similar comes down to comparing the input pose and projection of the model on the input. (see image with plots)

[image]

**My question is, what is the best method to compare the input pose and the project of the model?**

Until now, I calculate the **Euclidean distance** between each matching point. For normalization, I first divide each coordinate value by the image pixel width or height. 
I consider the maximum euclidean distance of all matching points and the sum of all euclidean distances. With the help of a determined threshold, it's decided if the two poses match.

*I have read about different algorithms for calculating image similarity (like Mahalanobis, Cosine, [Pearson] correlation), BUT I think these are overkill for this case. Here, only 18 sets of points are considered and they are already matched.*

Comment: Instead of normalizing by image size, you should find the scaling that minimizes the error norm (whichever you choose). Your affine transform already minimizes the Euclidean norm, so no additional scaling would be best. You could also try the sum of distances (=mean absolute error) or maximum distance as alternative norms.

Comment: Hey @CrisLuengo, thanks for your comment. What do you mean with 'the scaling that minimizes the error norm'?

Comment: You say that you "divide each coordinate value by the image pixel width or height" after finding the affine transform that best matches the two sets of points. If both images are of the same size, this doesn't do anything. If they are of different sizes, it's counterproductive. You want to scale the point sets so that the error norm is minimal, so as to best compare *shapes*, as opposed to *position* within space. (1/2)

Comment: (Contd.) The affine transform scales such that the MSE is minimal. If that is your error norm, you're done normalizing. If you decide for a different error norm, you could use that one to optimize scaling after your affine transform. But it's not necessary.